# Reset on loss of audio

Tags: audio, streaming

I am using a Pi in Kiosk mode to read a live HTML stream for the blind. Does anyone know how to reboot the PI, or the browser, if the stream fails or the audio stops?
I am using Chrome for the Kiosk browser and accessing the web link of thesightseer.org/listen. This automatically plays a embedded audio stream. Sometimes the stream fails and I need a way to restart it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this without more information. Please edit your question to include, at a minimum, what software you're using to run the Pi as a kiosk and how you're using that to read the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you to see if audio is playing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404952/5730361
You could check this periodically and reboot the RPi or restart the stream if this fails.